# How to create GPA calculator software application where the program stores data entered by user

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

the program allows user to key in module id,module grade,module credit and module code.The application will store all these information into a text file.student may also use the application to retrieve all his modules’ information and displayed them out. Lastly, the application must be able to calculate and display the student’s GPA.How do i do code this program...i atleast need a guide with the psedocode and comments.I only have a rough idea that i should use system.IO,exception handlers to code this program..please help me as i am new to c# programming. I have done my GUI design and some commentings..please take a look at it.http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/3364/guidesign.jpg click on this link to see my GUI design .

Answer (score 0):

You could start by thinking about the classes involved and their properties. A `Module` class with `Id`, `Code`, `Credit` and `Grade` properties should be fine. [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) and [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) methods will then help you store and retrieve information into a text file. You will also need an intermediary helper class that will convert the `Module` class into a string so that it could be stored into the text file.